# Next best offer models in recommendation system

Tags: machine-learning, python, recommender-system

I'm trying to so some research on "Next Best Offer" or "Next Best Action" models used in recommendation systems. Searched on google but didn't find any article with detailed algorithms/examples.

Does anyone know any model name in this area, maybe I can start from there?
If you know any python examples, that's even better!

Comment: This question is a bit opaque, which will make it challenging to answer. Can you [edit] your post to provide a link to where you came upon this term?

Comment: There is no link, I joined a new company, attending the meetings before being able to setup my laptop, and my team asked me to look into "Next Best Offer" model

Comment: Whenever I need to get started in a new topic, I try and find some literature to get started with. In this case, the exact phrase "next best offer" has about 500 results in Google scholar: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C47&q=%22next+best+offer%22+model&btnG=

Comment: Great, thank you! I will check these!